# how to capture audio by using dummy sound card driver?

Tags: alsa

I hope to know how to capture audio by using dummy sound card driver.

I'm thinking how to implement the steps below.

1. we play audio in ubuntu, however the audio is just played through dummy sound card driver, to capture audio stream.
2. captured audio is sent to windows through network.
3. audio is actually played in windows.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to activate ALSA `snd-aloop` module, that provides a full-duplex virtual loopback soundcard. Please have a look to the following links for instructions about activation and example usage:

https://github.com/TheSalarKhan/Linux-Audio-Loopback-Device

https://sysplay.in/blog/linux/2019/06/playing-with-alsa-loopback-devices/

A couple of important points to consider:

- The subdevices are linked in pairs; whatever you play on `hw:n,0,m` goes out on `hw:n,1,m` (see the example in the 1st link)
- The first application opening one of the subdevices will force the second application to use the same set of parameters: sample rate, format, number of channels. For example, suppose the recording application opens a capture stream on `hw:2,1,0` with stereo/44100/S16_LE format; the playback application on `hw:2,1,0` will be forced to use a the same stereo/44100/S16_LE format

Hope this helps